# Connecting Monero Light Wallet on Tails with Remote Node

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monerod-commands, tor, remote-node

I have downloaded Monero Command Line Interface on Tails and I tried connecting it to a remote node with this command as described here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero

Command:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
```

It succeded!

But when I ran this command, I got this error!

```
DNS_PUBLIC=tcp TORSOCKS_ALLOW_INBOUND=1 torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 85.194.238.131 --rpc-port-ip 18081 --confirm-external-bind
```

It shows that it failed to bind the server `85.194.238.131:18081`

I spent hours trying connecting it to remote node but failed to do so.
Please explain me how should I connect my walla et to remote node.

Answer (score 1):

Many remote node servers use the port `18089` as explained on [Connecting to the remote node from the wallet](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/remote_node_gui.html), so you should try using that port.